# Swift struct equivalent to C++ mutable keyword?

Tags: swift, mutable, mutating-function

Is there an equivalent in swift for the C++ `mutable` keyword? I have a struct implementing a protocol including a non-mutating function, however the implementation internally does mutate internal state. Is there any way to make a member var of the class mutable by this function, without changing the protocol definition, making the function `mutating`?

e.g.

```
public protocol P {
    // f is semantically unmutating
    func f
}

public struct S : P {
    // f is semantically unmutating, but does change some internal state
    public func f {
        v += 1
    }
    private var v: Int // How to mark this as mutable for internal purposes?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as in c++

```
public struct S : P {
    // f is semantically unmutating, but does change some internal state
    public func f {
       increment()
    }
    private mutating func increment() {
       v += 1
    }
    private var v: Int // How to mark this as mutable for internal purposes?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you are trying to do other than change the semantics of the protocol to `mutating` f()

Your only option is to create a new mutating version of protocol P `MutatingP` and then have the structure extend `MutatingP`. This can have the `mutating func f()` function which you can implement in the structure

This is essentially same as the other answer though.

Here's another very crooked solution. But it kind of satisfies your requirements. You will need to work with two global variables. An `Int` variable `V` and `struct S` variable `aStruct`. The code is is pretty much self explanatory. The biggest problem in this approach is that you cant have two struct instances at the same time. But this can be handled by using array of struct instead of a single struct.

Bottom line it kind of keeps the unmutating semantic of the protocol but still lets you mutate the variable. A simpler way could be devised using the same approach.

```
import UIKit

protocol P {
    func f()
}

var aStruct:S!
var V = 100 {
    didSet {
        print("changed V to \(V)")
        if var s = aStruct {
            s.v = 200
        }
    }
}

struct S : P  {
    var v:Int = 100 {
        didSet {
            aStruct = self
        }
    }
    init() {
        aStruct = self
    }
    func f() {
        V = 200
    }
}

let s = S()
s.f()
print("s.v = \(s.v)...aStruct.v = \(aStruct.v)")
```